# How can I deal with the diacetyl produced by pedio in a flanders red

Tags: sour, brettanomyces, pediococcus

I have a bunch of Flanders Red that has undergone a Pedio Fermentation and of course produced a bunch of diacetyl. This was done with the Wyeast Roeselare Ale Blend and then Barrel aged, then racked to carboy, its been in Carboy for a few years now. Ideally I would like to get rid of most of the diacetyl if possible. Suggestions?

I'm thinking rack it on to some pitted cherries and add more Brett.

Comment: How'd this turn out? I have a 2 year old Flanders Red blend that has been expressing some minor buttery off-flavors too - which I am assuming is diacetyl, since I definitely involved some Pedio-rich dregs from quite a few of my favorite dark sours. I still am pretty stoked with what I got, but if I can combat any off-flavor, I'm game to try.

Comment: Still haven't got around to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to catch diacetyl early and do a diacetyl (increase temp 68-72F) rest before racking off the yeast. Usually the diacetyl from bacteria is cleaned up by true brett, not so much by faux brett.

You may be able to trick yeast into cleaning this up by racking this onto the trub if a fresh beer and getting it warm. Or by growing a full pitch of healthy yeast that's prepared for the immediate contact with your ABV. In either case you want yeast to be past the growth phase and need for oxygen.

I would fine the beer as much as possible before the repitch removing as much of the Brett as possible.

Comment: The beer was pretty darn clean out of the barrel. So a diacetyl rest wasn't needed then. We drank a bunch and put some away...The pedio is the culprit, I have a mild in the planning stages and your idea of dumping it on that yeast cake is a good one, that should scrub it pretty good. Its a great beer it just needs less diacetyl...

Comment: Why the recommendation to remove the Bret (as much as possible)? Would the Brettanomyces and the Saccharomyces not play well together in this context?

Comment: @barking.pete just as a precaution to prevent flavor change. Getting the Brett active again may negate the mellowing from aging, adding new funk that may not be desirable.